# How to make "document.write" in an if statement work on the same html page rather than a new blank page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript `document.write` in an if statement.  So far when I do this, it writes what is supposed to be in the `document.write` on a new blank page.  I want to figure out how to make it so that the text that is supposed to be written is printed on the same page rather than a new blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document.write` can only be used when the document is still being loaded, so any attempt to use this after would mean that it writes to a new document.

You'll want to set the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML) of the element instead.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, I used innerHTML to create a div in which text is printed.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with being in an `if` statement, it has to do with using `document.write` when the document is in a closed state. Using it then will open a new document to write to. There is no way around that.

Use [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) instead of `document.write`.

Comment: I understand that it does not have to do with an if statement I just said that to explain the context of where it was located.  So do you think I should make a div where the text should appear and then use DOM manipulation?

Comment: I can't say what the best approach for determining where to put the content is without a lot more context, but adding a div is probably reasonable.